# Send a mail with java and gmail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I wanto to send a e-mail with an calendar attachment javaxmail and I created this class:

```
public void sendEmail(String to, Calendar calendar) {
    try {
        String  d_uname = "myaccount@gmail.com";
        String    d_password = "mypassword";
        String d_host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String  d_port  = "587";//465,587

        String from = "antonitocea@gmail.com";

        String subject = "Subject";
        String bodyText = "Body";

        Properties prop = new Properties();

        //prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.protocol", "smtps");
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.port",d_port);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", d_uname);


        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
        // Define message
        session.setDebug(true);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
        message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
        message.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT");


        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Outlook Meeting Request Using JavaMail");

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        StringBuffer buffer = sb.append(calendar.toString());

        // Create the message part 
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Fill the message 
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","calendar_message");
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
                new ByteArrayDataSource(buffer.toString(), "text/calendar")));//very important


        // Create a Multipart 
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Add part one 
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect(d_host, 587, d_uname, d_password);


        // Put parts in message 
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // send message 
        t.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It seems ok, but, when I try to send, the console shows this error:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: the username should be whithout '@' and domain?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code.

```
public void sendTemplateEmail() {

        Properties props = new Properties();  
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);  
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 25);  
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        Session mailSession = null;

        mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,  
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
                return new PasswordAuthentication("<Gmail User Name>", "<Gmail Password>");  
            }  
        });  


        try {

            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

            message.setSubject("Sample Subject");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Sample@sample.com"));
            String []to = new String[]{"Sample2gmail.com"};
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[0]));
            String body = "Sample text";
            message.setContent(body,"text/html");
            transport.connect();

            transport.sendMessage(message,message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
    }
```

Replace all the from and to email addresses and the  and  in the above code.

Comment: This code shows the same error that my code.  

"Permission denied: connect".
Thanks¡
I don't understand what is worng.

Comment: I tested the code. It is working perfectly. Can you post the error message what your getting? For authentication, you need to provide your gmail address and the password.

Comment: this is the trace of my error.
##
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolCo..

Comment: Can you test my code to check if it is rigth? If then, it could be network problem..

Comment: Can you change the port from 587 to 25? Looks like, port 587 is not opened.

Comment: Oh no, it isn't the problem. The conection is already refuse with the same error.

Comment: Can you do telnet smtp.gmail.com:587? and see whether the connection is established or not?

Comment: Run my code and see whether, we  able to receive the mail or not? Then, you can modify the code according to your requirement.

Comment: I can´t conect telent to smtp.gmail.com with 587 por, the console shows "conection closes by remote host" and "Permission denied". As I was suposed, it should be network problem